# Make TableViewColumn not resizeable

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.3

I've got a TableView with two TableViewColumns and would like to prevent them from being resized.
How can I do this?

```
TableView {

   TableViewColumn {
      title: "Name"
      width: parent.width - 20
   }

   TableViewColumn {
      width: 18
      delegate: CheckBox {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  TableViewColumn {
     title: "Name"
     width: parent.width - 20
     resizable: false
  }
```